# Help to understand the geodesics in $BS(1, 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I would like to understand the sets of geodesics in $BS(1, 2)$, which is described in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05321.pdf, Proposition 3 (page 3).

> Write $$ G=B S(1, 2)=\left\langle a, t \mid t a
>  t^{-1}=a^2\right\rangle $$
> Let $\mathbb{Z}_2=\left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid k^e x \in
> > \mathbb{Z}\right.$ for some $\left.e \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ and
> consider the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$,
> where the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is multiplication
> by $2$. Then $B S(1, 2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$.
> Proposition 3. Let $G=B S(1,2)$. The set of words in
> the following forms comprise a set of unique geodesic representatives
> for the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
>
> 2a. $\left\{\epsilon, a^{ \pm 1}, a^{ \pm 2}, a^{ \pm 3}\right\}$
>
> 2b. $\left\{a^{x_0} t a^{x_1} t \cdots a^{x_d} t^{-d}|d \geq 1,| x_d
> \mid \in\{2,3\}, A\right\}$
>
> 2c. $\left\{t^{-b} a^{x_0} t a^{x_1} \cdots t a^{x_d} t^{-c}\left|b,
> c, d \geq 1, d=b+c, x_0 \neq 0,\right| x_d \mid \in\{2,3\}, A\right\}$
>
> 2d. $\left\{t^{-d} a^{x_0} t \cdots t a^{x_d} \mid d \geq 1, x_0 \neq
> 0, A\right\}$
>
> Here, $A$ signifies the conditions $\left|x_i\right| \leq 1$ for
> $i<d$, if $x_{i-1} \neq 0$ then $x_i=0$ for $i<d$, if $x_d>0$ then
> $x_{d-1} \geq 0$, and if $x_d<0$ then $x_{d-1} \leq 0$.

If I understand the condition $A$ correctly, $w= a^{-1}ta^{0}ta^2 t^{-2}$ is an element in the set described in (2b), but $w$ can also be represented by $ a^1 t a^3 t^{-1}$ which has a shorter length. Did I misunderstand something here?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: From our guidelines for [Formatting and Writing Your Post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992): *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.* So please add enough information to your post that we know what all those letters represent. I can guess what they might mean, but I might guess wrong, and so I am disinclined to write an answer yet.